# login with a wordpress generated password in a non-wp environment

Tags: wordpress, passwords

My client gave me a bunch of databases with wordpress generated passwords. Now he wants me to make a login system, but not with wordpress (I must use those wp-generated passwords). Is there a way to make use of those passwords?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IF you know what algorythm was used to encrypt passwords in your Wordpress database, you can easily write your own function for comparing passwords for your login system using the same HASH.

Here is some more info on WP_HASH: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

EDIT: Very good article about Wordpress Password Hashes: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wordpress-password-hashes/